# Wrapper function breaks socket.io function

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, client-server

**Problem**:

When I wrap a function around a socket.emit() keyboard input function it doesn't work as intended.
I am using Node(10.15.3), express(4.17.1) and socket.io(2.2.0) to send data between client and server.

**What works as expected:** I have used the wrapper function keyIsPressed(id, isPressed) only for the document.keydowndown event and then the only the socket.emit function for the document.onkeyup.

**What doesn't work as expected:** Using the wrapper function keyIsPressed(id, isPressed) for document.onkeyup event. The player stops moving after I have pressed all 4 moving keys at least once.

socket.emit function:

```
    socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: id, state: isPressed});
```

Wrapper Function:

```
    function keyIsPressed(id, isPressed){
       socket.emit('keyPress', {inputId: id, state: isPressed});
    }
```

keyCodes put into object

```
    var key = {
        d: 68,
        s: 83,
        a: 65,
        w: 87,
    }
```

Implementation of wrapper function at event *onkeydown*:

```
 document.onkeydown = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === key.d) {
            keyIsPressed('right', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'right', state: true});
        }
        if (event.keyCode === key.s) {
            keyIsPressed('down', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'down', state: true});
        }
        if (event.keyCode === key.a) {
            keyIsPressed('left', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'left', state: true });
        }
        if (event.keyCode === key.w) {
            keyIsPressed('up', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'up', state: true});
        }        
    }
```

Implementation of wrapper function at event *onkeyup*:

```
document.onkeydown = (event) => {
        if (event.keyCode === key.d) {
            keyIsPressed('right', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'right', state: true});
        }
        if (event.keyCode === key.s) {
            keyIsPressed('down', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'down', state: true});
        }
        if (event.keyCode === key.a) {
            keyIsPressed('left', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'left', state: true });
        }
        if (event.keyCode === key.w) {
            keyIsPressed('up', true)
            // socket.emit('keyPress', { inputId: 'up', state: true});
        }        
    }
```

socket.on function:

```
socket.on('keyPress', (data) =>{
    if(data.inputId === 'right'){
        player.pressing.right = data.state;
    } 
    else if (data.inputId === 'left') {
        player.pressing.left = data.state;
    } 
    else if (data.inputId === 'down') {
        player.pressing.down = data.state;
    } 
    else if (data.inputId === 'up') {
        player.pressing.up = data.state;
    } 
});
```

´´´

---

here is the git repo and commit where I am seeing this problem:
https://github.com/crabman84/NodeProjects/tree/d8b7f6b56c0b1ccd4d54eaac62c6f45824fcf5d2/MBG

---

I expect to be able to type A,W,S,D and move the player in its respective direction while the code is running.

This moves the player in its direction but won't stop when I stop pressing its respective key.

This won't stop moving until I press the key in its opposite direction and the player will no longer move for the program duration.